# Override an attribute value of global element in XSD

Tags: xsd, xsd-1.1

I have a use case where I need to reuse a global element. However, there is a certain attribute whose value I want to override. Following is an XSD

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="b" type="bType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="a" type="bType">
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="bType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="type">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="Hey"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The XML corresponding to above XSD is as follows

```
<root>
    <a type="Hey">
        <name>kjre</name>
    </a>
</root>
```

I want to override value of this type attribute in "a" element. Since all the element definition in "bType" is exactly how I want it, I wanted to use bType with only difference being in value of "type" attribute. I needed a way in which XSD will be same but overriding of value of "type" is permitted. In short, I wanted something as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="b" type="bType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="a" type="bType">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="type">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Eat"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:attribute>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="bType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="type">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="Hey"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

So the XML corresponding to the XSD can be :

```
<root>
    <a type="Eat">
        <name>kjre</name>
    </a>
</root>
```

Is it possible in XSD 1.1?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what requirements the new schema is expected to satisfy.

It won't be the case that documents valid against the new schema will be valid against the old one, so it's unlikely that any tooling created for the old schema would be reusable against the new one.  So why bother trying to derive the new schema from the old one?  Why not just copy the files and modify the enumeration for the values of the `type` attribute?  If there is an answer to this question, it may shed some light on what your actual requirements are.

If there are no requirements, then any answer will do, and you are unlikely to get any useful answers.

If the answer is "I want to use the old tooling", then as just mentioned above there is no solution: the tooling for the old schema is set up to expect precisely the values enumerated in the old schema -- adding new values is just the kind of thing that will break the tooling.

If the answer is "I want to be able to adopt new versions of the underlying schema as easily and quickly as possible, and I want a clear demarcation of what has been changed locally vis-a-vis the underlying schema", then I'd suggest using XSD 1.1 and using the xsd:redefine facility.  There is not a great way to specify that you just want to change the anonymous type embedded inside an attribute declaration inside an element declaration inside a named type -- the maker of the base schema has signaled pretty clearly that the set of enumerated values for the 'type' attribute is not intended to be reusable, or independently modifiable, or a 'thing' in any serious say -- but redefine will let you provide a new definition of `{}bType` and leave everything else the same.

If the answer is something else, then there may be other usable approaches.

Comment: I am coming here really late as I had halted this task for some time. The new schema was supposed to override value of `type` attribute of `bType` for element `a`.So you mean that If I have a complexType whose attributes have some enumeration values, I cannot extend this complexType AND change the values of the enumeration?

Comment: If all you want is a schema with a different enumerated value of `type`, nothing is stopping you from writing one.  If you have additional requirements that won't be met by writing a new schema or modifying the old one in place, you need to say what those requirements are, or you are unlikely to get any useful responses.